# How do I run a single @testset in Julia?

Tags: unit-testing, julia

I'm new to Julia, and I'm trying to figure out how to run a single @testset, rather than run all the tests for my package. My current workflow is to run:

```
julia> ]
(@v1.9 pkg) > activate .
(MyPackage pkg) > test
```

I'm open to other workflows, and hoping for something like an arg where I express the nested name of my underlying testset.

I ran the help for test in the pkg prompt, but didn't see an option to specify individual testsets. I also tried:

```
(MyPackage pkg) > test MyTest
```

But that failed because it was looking for a package named MyTest, not a testset named MyTest within MyPackage.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible. `@test` looks for the PACKAGENAME/test/runtests.jl, and runs the file contents. To only run a subset of the tests found in that file, I would recommend multi-line commenting out the sections to ignore, saving it, and running `@test`. As a side note for testing packages, it's unnecessary to activate an environment to test it- you can simply use `]test PACKAGENAME`.

Comment: The `Test` standard library doesn't have this, but there are external packages like [ReTest.jl](https://github.com/JuliaTesting/ReTest.jl/) and [TestItemRunner.jl](https://github.com/julia-vscode/TestItemRunner.jl) that have this feature.

Comment: I manually added some conditions based on command line args in order to test all or a part of my test (but not on individual testsets).. see the test script of [BetaML jl](https://github.com/sylvaticus/BetaML.jl)

Comment: Thanks folks. I'll check out the packages Sundar recommended. In other languages I've found the workflow of running just a single test quite productive, so I can focus on the task at hand before making sure I didn't break something else by running all tests.